# How to install the "Optional GCC 5.2 Suite" in SLES 11 SP4 SDK?

Tags: sles, sles11

The [release notes for SUSE Enterprise Linux Server 11 SP4](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/11-SP4/#fate-319015) say:

> The optional compiler on the SDK has been updated to GCC 5.2. It brings improvements in C++ language support, including full C++11 support in the runtime library and the compiler as well as support for most C++14 changes.

Sounds great! But when I actually look on the SDK ISO, I don't see GCC 5 anywhere, only GCC 4.8.

```
# cat media.1/products
/ SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Software-Development-Kit-11-SP4 11.4.4-1.55
# find /mnt -name '*gcc*' 
/mnt/suse/x86_64/cross-spu-gcc-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.24.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/cross-spu-gcc-static-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.24.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc33-fortran-32bit-3.3.3-11.9.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc33-32bit-3.3.3-11.9.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc33-3.3.3-11.9.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc33-fortran-3.3.3-11.9.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc43-fortran-32bit-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.30.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc43-gij-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.46.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc43-objc-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.30.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc43-objc-32bit-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.30.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc43-ada-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.30.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc43-fortran-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.30.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc43-gij-32bit-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.46.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc43-java-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.46.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc43-obj-c++-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.30.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc48-fortran-4.8.3+r212056-2.17.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc48-32bit-4.8.3+r212056-2.17.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc48-4.8.3+r212056-2.17.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc48-c++-4.8.3+r212056-2.17.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc48-fortran-32bit-4.8.3+r212056-2.17.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc48-info-4.8.3+r212056-2.17.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc48-locale-4.8.3+r212056-2.17.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc-ada-4.3-62.200.2.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc-fortran-4.3-62.200.5.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc-fortran-32bit-4.3-62.200.5.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc-gij-32bit-4.3-62.200.2.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc-gij-4.3-62.200.2.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc-java-4.3-62.200.2.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc-objc-4.3-62.200.2.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc-objc-32bit-4.3-62.200.2.x86_64.rpm
/mnt/suse/x86_64/gcc-obj-c++-4.3-62.200.2.x86_64.rpm
```

I'm guessing the release notes are just wrong, but would be happy to be shown otherwise.

Do SUSE provide a newer compiler for SLSE 11 than the GCC 4.8 in SLES 11 SP4 SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe GCC 5.2 was provided after the SDK media was created hence the reason it's missing from the ISO.

If your server is registered with the SLE11 SP4 SDK repos enabled you should be able to do "zypper in gcc5" to install GCC 5.2.

HTH,
Simon (SUSE Knowledge Partner)

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. I'm accepting this answer even though I can't test it. I only have access to what's available through the free SLES developer program, which is SLES 12 only. So I wouldn't have had my SLES 11 system registered. Ultimately we ended up just dropping support for SLES 11 for our product. Our primary customer for this was upgrading to SLES 12, so no harm done.